# GDI: Original DC bitmap changes, and can't restore

Tags: winapi, memory-leaks, mfc, gdi

I'm seeing an issue where I could not re-select the original bitmap on a DC, causing a memory leak. The pointer to the original bitmap stayed the same throughout the program, but the data (from CBitmap::GetBitmap) changes from monochrome to something else. I don't know when the bitmap actually changes, but something in the system is causing it.

```
CBitmap* cMyClass::mpOldBitmap;
CDC cMyClass::mCanvasDc;
CBitmap cMyClass::mCanvasBmp;

void cMyClass::Init()
{
    // One-time initialization
    CDC* pDc = GetDC();
    mCanvasDc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDc);
    mCanvasBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDc, 10, 10);
    mpOldBitmap = mCanvasDc.SelectObject(&mCanvasBmp);
    ReleaseDC(pDc);

    BITMAP bitmap;
    mpOldBitmap->GetBitmap(&bitmap); // A monochrome bitmap, as expected.
}

void cMyClass::Recreate(int newW, int newH)
{
    // 1. Delete existing bitmap:
    if (mpOldBitmap)
    {
        BITMAP bitmap;
        mpOldBitmap->GetBitmap(&bitmap); // This is no longer the monochrome bitmap. It is 8bpp, with random size.

        CBitmap* pCurrBmp = mCanvasDc.SelectObject(mpOldBitmap); // This fails (NULL). I can't de-select my bitmap.
        mCanvasBmp.DeleteObject(); // This fails too, causing memory leak. Actually, it fails in CE6, but not in Win32. Regardless, both platforms will have a memory leak.
    }

    // 2. Recreate the bitmap with new size:
    {
        CDC* pDc = GetDC();
        mCanvasBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDc, newW, newH);
        ReleaseDC(pDc);
    }

    // 3. Finalize
    mpOldBitmap = mCanvasDc.SelectObject(&mCanvasBmp);
}
```

1. Any known scenarios where this can happen?
2. Any debugging tips to break when the bitmap data changes?

Note: In code, I mentioned "this fails". I remove the assert on the returned values to make the code readable.

---

Edit: The solution that I am using to fix it is to use CDC:SaveDC and CDC::RestoreDC instead of stashing the pointer. The memory leak went away, and every GDI call passed.  But I am still curious why the original code leaked.  The pointer to the default bitmap, as far as I know, should be a default monochrome bitmap that is probably global in GDI world

Comment: [mcve] required.

Comment: I think your problem is that you cannot manipulate (recreate) an instance variable like this. You need a pointer to CBitmap, i.e. CBitmap* mCanvasBmp and "delete" it and recreate it like mCanvasBmp = new CBitmap everytime.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see the code from OP.

```
mpOldBitmap = mCanvasDc.SelectObject(mCanvasBmp);
```

Because mCanvasBmp is a CBitmap object (not a pointer to CBitmap), first is called the HGDIOBJ operator, then **CDC::SelectObject(HGDIOBJ)** which returns **HGDIOBJ** and not **CBitmap***. This should give a conversion compiler error. If cast the returned value to CBitmap* is also wrong.

The correct way to get rid of problem is to pass a pointer.

```
mpOldBitmap = mCanvasDc.SelectObject(& mCanvasBmp);
```

This case will be called **CDC::SelectObject(CBitmap* pBitmap)** which returns a **CBitmap***.

// I hope it's pretty clear. :)

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo on my part while trying to simplify the code for SO.  I've corrected the description.  I've also added the solution that I found, but I am still curious why the original didn't work.